# How covert C# DateTime to Java DateTimeusing Joda-Time

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I am new to Joda and need help. I am trying to convert this C# code to java. I have been doing some research on Joda-time as well as looking at the documentation for the library. I am trying to get the difference epoch and UTC now(). but not sure how to achieve this using Joda's Interval class. Here is the C# method getting epoch and checking it against UTC now(). Then getting the difference between the two dates.

```
public static void AddApiAuthenticationHeaders(this HttpClient httpClient, HttpMethod httpMethod, string publicKey, string privateKey)
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-PSK", "thisisatestpublickey");//key:K-PSK

        DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970,01,01,0,0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc); //Getting UTC DATE since epoch
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart; //get the current timestamp between now and january 1970
        string stamp = Convert.ToUInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString(); //get the total seconds that have elasped

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Stamp", stamp);
        //research extension method
        string[] data = new string[] {publicKey, stamp.ToString(), httpMethod.Method };
        byte[] expectedSignature = data.ComputeHash(privateKey);

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HttpRequestMessageExtensions.SignatureHeaderName, Convert.ToBase64String(expectedSignature));
    }
```

This works fine but now I want to do the same thing in java using Joda.

This is what I have been trying to do but am I am to understand how to get the difference in the two time using the Interval class.

```
 DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0, DateTimeZone.UTC);

    Interval ts = new Interval(DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis(), epochStart.getMillis());

    String stamp = ts.toString(); // I know here is not right
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really a C# expert, but this block of code:

```
DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970,01,01,0,0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc); //Getting UTC DATE since epoch
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart; //get the current timestamp between now and january 1970
string stamp = Convert.ToUInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString(); //get the total seconds that have elasped
```

Appears to just get the number of seconds since the epoch and convert it to a string.  So here is the equivalent Java code:

```
String stamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
```

Comment: why divided by 1000? and are you saying the 3 lines of c# code is that one line in java code, including the difference between `TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart;`?

Comment: Because there are 1000 milliseconds in a second, and you want seconds. And yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: Ok gonna give it a shot and let you know happens